# How to assign Kana (かな) key in Japanese keyboard to another Language?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, internationalization, language

I have purchased my Mac Pro ( it is running OS 10.9.5) in Japan. Needless to say that it has two different keys assigned exclusively for English and Japanese (英語 for English and かな for Japanese).

But the issue is that I'd like to change the かな key to a third Language (Persian in fact, that I am using in addition to English).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with karabiner. I have changed my kana key to simple Chinese input method.

Here is the website: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner

Comment: Can you tell us more. I installed and opened karabiner but still don't know how to change?